# Does anyone know how to calculate software costs for Windows Azure Reserved Instances?

Tags: azure

I am aware of these links:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/billing/billing-reserved-instance-windows-software-costs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/mt219004(v=azure.100)

The second link suggests that I have to make REST calls to get the cost. I am trying to make sense of the sample JSON responses:

```
"Meters": [  
      {  
         "MeterId": "1822fcc4-6059-4cbb-a132-54a187aaac46",  
         "MeterName": "Compute Hours",  
         "MeterCategory": "Virtual Machines",  
         "MeterSubCategory": "Basic_D6 VM (Non-Windows)",  
         "Unit": "Hours",  
         "MeterTags": [],  
         "MeterRates": {  
            "0": 3.136  
         },  
         "EffectiveDate": "2015-02-01T00:00:00Z",  
         "IncludedQuantity": 0.0  
      },
```

How am I to interpret this? In this sample, does it mean that the software cost is $3.136/hour? Any guidance is appreciated.

Edit:

Does the pricing calculator include software costs?

Comment: Which software costs? Are you talking about OS or some other application? The pricing calculator does include the cost of the OS. If you are looking to leverage Azure Hybrid Use Benefits, there is an option to enable that which deducts the cost of the windows license. There is also a link that explains the criteria for using AHUB.

Comment: OS costs. If the pricing calculator includes the OS cost, that clarifies my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest use Azure pricing calculator

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/

You can compare the reserved instances with the all different options available.

[image: Option use your existing license for the OS]

Azure Hybrid helps to use your existing license, The above diagram includes the OS cost.

Comment: I should have added this to my question (will edit it shortly): Does the pricing calculator include software costs?

Comment: Yes it includes the OS Cost. There is an option to enable hybrid, which helps to bring you on-premises OS to Azure *** "Save up to 40% with Windows Server Licenses you already own. Learn more about Azure Hybrid" ***